# JSON data null in controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I am working to send multiple `email/SMS` by selecting the checkbox. And When I am receiving in my javascript function it's getting with data. But when I pass it to action method record count shows but all data are null. Below is my code with screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq6bl.png)

Here it is my Model:

```
 public class BulkEmailSendViewModel
    {
        public BulkEmailSendViewModel()
        {
            Candidates = new List<CandidateData>();
        }
        public List<CandidateData> Candidates { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }

    }
    public class CandidateData
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string CandidateId { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string CandidateName { get; internal set; }
    }
```

//Select all selected checkbox

```
  $("#bulkAction").change(function () {
        var ddlId = $("#bulkAction").val();//to get sms or email
        var chk_arr = $('.checkCandidate:checkbox:checked');
        var chklength = chk_arr.length;
        var json = '';
        $('.checkCandidate:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                var Phone = $(this).attr("candidatePhone");
                var CandidateId = $(this).attr("candidateId");
                var Email = $(this).attr("candidatEmail");
                var item = '{\"Phone\":\"' + Phone + '\","CandidateId\":\"' + CandidateId + '\",\"Email\":\"' + Email + '\",\"CandidateName\":\"\"},';
                json += item;
            }
        });
        json = "[" + json.substr(0, json.length - 1) + "]";
        SendBulkEmail(json);

    });
```

My Javascript:

```
function SendBulkEmail(jsonObj) {
    alert(jsonObj);
    if (jsonObj.length > 0) {
        var send = "/Utility/Notifications/BulkEmail";
        $(".modal-title").text("Send Email");
        //var data = {
        //    Candidates: eval(jsonObj)
        //};
        $.get(send, { bulkEmailSendViewModel: eval(jsonObj) }, function (result) {
            $("#C_modal_body").html("");
            $("#C_modal_body").html(result);
        });
    }
    else {
        $.alert("Email not found for this candidate.");
        // e.stopPropagation();
    }

}
```

My Controller:

```
 public PartialViewResult BulkEmail(List<CandidateData> bulkEmailSendViewModel)
        {
            BulkEmailSendViewModel bulkDetail = new BulkEmailSendViewModel();
            return PartialView(bulkDetail);
        }
```

Why my all values are null even I am getting in javascript function?

Comment: Did you try `JSON.stringify({ bulkEmailSendViewModel: eval(jsonObj) })`. Also consider making it Post request.

Comment: You're doing it the hard way by buiding json as a string and not an array of objects.

Comment: Open up Chrome, press f12, go to the network tab, click preserve log.  Now, when SendBulkEmail $.get sends, what are the headers being sent?  Is it valid JSON?  https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: side note: a "post" request would be more semantically suitable for this. What you're doing (sending) is the exact opposite of _get_ ting. Also why are you building your JSON as a string and then using "eval"? You can do it much more easily by just adding properties to an object (JSON _is_ a javascript object - the clue's in the name), without opening yourself up to syntax and encoding errors, or the security risks inherent with the use of eval.

Comment: Only other thing I can't see mentioned here is a `[FromBody]` tag on your `BulkEmail` controller function -  `public PartialViewResult BulkEmail([FromBody]List<CandidateData> bulkEmailSendViewModel)`

Answer (score 0):

change your javascript codes to this:

```
 $("#bulkAction").change(function () {
    var ddlId = $("#bulkAction").val();//to get sms or email
    var chk_arr = $('.checkCandidate:checkbox:checked');
    var chklength = chk_arr.length;
    var data = [];
    $('.checkCandidate:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            var Phone = $(this).attr("candidatePhone");
            var CandidateId = $(this).attr("candidateId");
            var Email = $(this).attr("candidatEmail");
            var item = {Phone: Phone,
                        CandidateId: CandidateId,
                        Email : Email,
                        CandidateName : ""};
            data.push(item);
        }
    });
    SendBulkEmail(data);
});
```

and the `SendBulkEmail` to:

```
function SendBulkEmail(data) {
if (data.length > 0) {
    var send = "/Utility/Notifications/BulkEmail";
    $(".modal-title").text("Send Email");
    //var data = {
    //    Candidates: eval(jsonObj)
    //};
    $.post(send, { bulkEmailSendViewModel: JSON.stringify(data) }, function (result) {
        $("#C_modal_body").html("");
        $("#C_modal_body").html(result);
    });
}
else {
    $.alert("Email not found for this candidate.");
    // e.stopPropagation();
 }
}
```

and finally:

```
[HttpPost] 
public PartialViewResult BulkEmail(List<CandidateData> bulkEmailSendViewModel)
        {
            BulkEmailSendViewModel bulkDetail = new BulkEmailSendViewModel();
            return PartialView(bulkDetail);
        }
```

Comment: thanks it worked but not with json.stringify. It worked with eval

Comment: Please mark an answer as a correct if you got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, I don't see any use of the bulkEmailSendViewModel input parameter.

Maybe, you could propagate the candidate list as follow:

```
public PartialViewResult BulkEmail(List<CandidateData> candidates)
{
    BulkEmailSendViewModel bulkDetail=new BulkEmailSendViewModel();
    bulkDetail.candidates = candidates;
    return PartialView(bulkDetail);
}
```